# Replace part of a string with anchor tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a sentence: "This is a sentence with a link1, also it has link2"
It is in p tag.
I also have data when it starts and when it ends, respectively:

```
[{ start: 26, end: 31 }, { start: 45, end: 50 }]
```

Is it possible to replace these parts of the sentence with anchor tags having upper data available. As a result it would be a something like this:

```
<p>This is a sentence with a <a>link1</a>, also it has <a>link2</a></p>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building a string of HTML and/or using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is not the correct solution here. To solve this the "React way," consider that this structure:

```html
<p>This is a sentence with a <a>link1</a>, also it has <a>link2</a></p>
```

...could be generated with this React component (this is more verbose than necessary, just for clarity's sake):

```jsx
const LinkText = () => {
  const parts = [
    'This is a sentence with a ',
    <a>{'link1'}</a>,
    ', also it has ',
    <a>{'link2'}</a>,
  ];
  return <p>{parts}</p>;
};
```

With that in mind, the question is this: How do we generate the `parts` array from a string and an array of link positions? The solution is to iterate over the array of link positions and, in each iteration, push onto the array 1) The "non-link" text between the previous link position's `end` (or the start of the string), and 2) an `<a>` containing the current link position's `start` and `end`. A simple, working implementation looks like this:

```js
const LinkText = ({ text, linkPositions }) => {
  const parts = [];
  let currentIndex = 0;
  
  linkPositions.forEach(({ start, end }) => {
    if (currentIndex < start) {
      parts.push(text.slice(currentIndex, start));
    }
    parts.push(<a>{text.slice(start, end)}</a>);
    currentIndex = end;
  });
  
  if (currentIndex < text.length - 1) {
    parts.push(text.slice(currentIndex)); // Remaining text after the last link
  }
  
  return <p>{parts}</p>;
};

const text = 'This is a sentence with a link1, also it has link2';
const links = [{ start: 26, end: 31 }, { start: 45, end: 50 }];

ReactDOM.render(<LinkText text={text} linkPositions={links}/>, document.querySelector('div'));
```

```css
a{color:blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do that is using IDs and JS.

So, for example, your HTML would look like this:

```
<p>This is a sentence with a <a id="linkOne">link1</a>, also it has <a id="linkTwo">link2</a></p>
```

And then your JS would call this:

```
document.getElementById("linkOne").href = "http://linkOne.com"
document.getElementById("linkTwo").href = "http://linkTwo.com"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve that with `str.replace` with a regex.

as @Dupocas said, React will escape html tags, so you will need to use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

```js
const str = 'This is a sentence with a link1, also it has link2';
const result = str.replace(/link(\d)/g, (match, linkId) => {
  return `<a href="${linkId}">${match}</a>`;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: My mistake, it is just an example but in real case it won't be a word with link inside

Answer (score -1):

You can use this snippet to replace the text at the specific places into links. I have sorted it in a descending order based on the start since changing it from the end of the string is easier.

```js
document.getElementById("convert").addEventListener("click", convertLinks);
addEventListener

function convertLinks() {
  var pTag = document.getElementById("test")

  var text = pTag.innerHTML

  posData = [{
    start: 26,
    end: 31
  }, {
    start: 45,
    end: 50
  }]

  posData = posData.sort(function(pos1, pos2) {
    return pos2.start - pos1.start
  })

  for (pos of posData) {
    text = replaceLink(text, pos)
  }

  pTag.innerHTML = text;
}

function replaceLink(text, pos) {
  return text.slice(0, pos.start) + "<a>" + text.slice(pos.start, pos.end) + "</a>" + text.slice(pos.end)
}
```

```css
a {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<p id="test">This is a sentence with a link1, also it has link2</p>

<button id="convert"> Convert Links </button>
```